# How to get active users( Online ) of another application near by you?

Tags: android, gps, pubnub

I am making one module which needs to be able to find another application 
Active users(Just like online or not) nearby within 4 km of radius, who are users of my another app(delivery app).

which 3rd party API should better for this pubnub or pusher? and How to achieve this?

I searched about pubnub presence API and Public/Subscribe Function.

**Module** Scenario :

**App A** :

clickEvent -> search for Active users of App B near by you within 4 KM of radius and publish notofication to that App B's users/
(I have Active and Non-Active users of App B with Web service call)

Comment: This blog is old but talks about PubNub for chatting by proximity (geohashing) https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-05-07-geohashing-chat-by-proximity/ - you would use PubNub Functions now to accomplish some of what you want to do. https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks-catalog?geolocation

Answer (score 0):

This blog is old but talks about PubNub for [chatting by proximity (geohashing)](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-05-07-geohashing-chat-by-proximity/)

You would use [PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks-catalog?geolocation) now to accomplish some of what you want to do.